# Custom PowerShell function that accepts arguments and pipe input

Tags: function, powershell

Currently I have the following code below, which does not work for me.
I would Like it to behave like this

```
some-output-from-some-function | FILTER_DATA
```

or

```
some-output-from-some-function | FILTER_DATA | Filter_01
```

With the function below (without the $id included) i need to catch the
some-output-from-some-function int ovariable and execute it like this (which does NOT suit me):

```
$a = some-output-from-some-function
"$a" | FILTER_DATA
```

Please help. I want it to be universal, not specific to one or two passed
arguments ...

```
Function FILTER_DATA ($id){
                      [CmdletBinding()]
                      Param(
                            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
                            $item
                           )
       $item | % {$PSItem.replace("&lt;","<").replace("&gt;",">")} |
               % {$PSItem -replace "<table>", "$description<table class=sortable id=$id" `
                          -replace "</table>","</table></span>" `
}}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the error you have.

Answer (score 1):

Param() can't be used if the arguments are passed in function declaration. In your case you passed `$ID` while declaring function. You can use below code which should work fine.

```
Function FILTER_DATA {
                      [CmdletBinding()]
                      Param(
                            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$item,
                            $ID
                            )
       $item | % {$PSItem.replace("&lt;","<").replace("&gt;",">")} |
               % {$PSItem -replace "<table>", "$description<table class=sortable id=$id" `
                          -replace "</table>","</table></span>" `}
}
```

And now FILTER_DATA can accept input `$Item` from pipeline.

Comment: hmmm, what about passing output of this custom function, to Another custom function … like: "$a"|FILTER_DATA|Filter_01

Comment: You need to configure `Filter_01` to accept `ValueFromPipeline` and it should work. You need to return value from `FILTER_DATA` function which can be piped to `Filter_01` function. In your `FILTER_DATA` function, it's not returning anything, so `Filter_01` doesn't have any input.